# Flutter webviews gives net::ERR_CACHE_MISS message

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

When using webview in flutter i am getting this message. 
here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class Webview extends StatelessWidget {
  String url;
  Webview({this.url});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      url: url,
      withJavascript: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      appCacheEnabled: false,
      withZoom: true,
      ignoreSSLErrors: true,
    );
  }
}
```

These are the permissions in debug/androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

I tried using webview_flutter and flutter_webview_plugin plugin both have the same issue.

The app works fine in simulators but when used on real devices I get thrown this error.
Please help and Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 49):

WebView in Debug is working because you have Internet permission in debug/androidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

add the same in  main/androidManifest.xml

Comment: This worked for me, I just had to run flutter clean after adding this.